# 2-step system-GMM for static panel models?

Tags: statistical-finance, estimation, gmm

Could we use the 2-step system generalized method of moment (GMM) for static regression models? As I know, 2-step system GMM is designed for dynamic panel data models but I see many papers use it for static models as well. Some other papers also include the lag of the dependent variable to their static model to make the model dynamic but does not explain the reason. Please enlighten me if you know something about it and provide reference (if possible). Many thanks.

Comment: You would gain more exposure if you ask this question on [Crossvalidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) instead of here.